# pyvirtualdisplay ImportError: cannot import name Display

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-14.04, xvfb

### My Ubuntu

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

### My Xvfb

```
$ apt --installed list | grep xvfb
xvfb/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 amd64 [installed]
```

### My python

```
python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

### My file

```
$more pyvirtualdisplay.py

#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Firefox will run in a virtual display. 
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

### When I run it

```
$ python pyvirtualdisplay.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyvirtualdisplay.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
  File "/root/pyvirtualdisplay.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
ImportError: cannot import name Display
```

### PyVirtualDisplay

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

$ pip list | grep PyVirtual
PyVirtualDisplay (0.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you never define `Display` in your code. The name of your python code coincides with the module name called `pyvirtualdisplay`.

The file name of your python code is called `pyvirtualdisplay.py` and you also try to import from a module called `pyvirtualdisplay`.

As you can see from your `pyvirtualdisplay.py`, there is no function with name `Display` defined anywhere.

Python uses below search path in sequence to find the module you are trying to import:

1. The home directory of the program
2. Diretories in environment variable `PYTHONPATH`
3. Standard library diretories
4. The contents of any `.pth` files

So, in your case, python is trying to search in the same directory as you run your `pyvirtualdisplay.py` and it is able to find the file with name `pyvirtualdisplay`. So, python tries to search Display in `pyvirtualdisplay.py` (your own code) and thus, is not able to find anything related. That's why it is complaining `cannot import name Display`.

My suggestion is that you could change the name of your python code to a different one, e.g. `pyvirtualdisplays.py` and that will work.

Comment: oh god ... could that be trivial?! I feel awfully embarrassed.

Comment: Yes of course!! Thanks for bothering answering such a silly problem, I am very very grateful. I was sidetracked by another issue.